# Spring does not instanciate bean with Map or List as property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm implementing a basic batch application using both Spring Boot and Spring Batch.

For each files found in the input directory, one step is created thanks to a `MultiResourcePartitioner`

```
<bean id="partitioner"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner">
    <description>
        Create a step for each files found in the input directory
    </description>
    <property name="resources" value="#{resourceProvider.read()}"/>
</bean>
```

Each step is composed of a ItemReader, ItemProcessor and ItemWriter. 
My problem is with the ItemReader, and as a matter of fact with every bean using a List/Map as a property in the xml configuration.

My ItemReader is the following :

```
<bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
    <description>
        * resource is set via step scoped late binding (see multiresourcereader)
        * strict mode - we expect input files
    </description>
    <property name="resource" value="#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}"/>
    <property name="strict" value="true"/>
    <property name="lineMapper" ref="lineMapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="lineMapper" class="input.CustomPatternMatchingLineMapper">
    <property name="fieldSetMappers">
        <map>
            <entry key="001*" value-ref="payloadFieldSetMapper"/>
            <entry key="000*" value-ref="headerFieldSetMapper"/>
            <entry key="999*" value-ref="footerFieldSetMapper"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="tokenizers">
        <map>
            <entry key="001*" value-ref="payloadTokenizer"/>
            <entry key="000*" value-ref="headerTokenizer"/>
            <entry key="999*" value-ref="footerTokenizer"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="headerTokenizer" class="input.tokenizer.HeaderTokenizer"/>
<bean id="payloadTokenizer" class="input.tokenizer.PayloadTokenizer"/>
<bean id="footerTokenizer" class="input.tokenizer.FooterTokenizer"/>

<bean id="headerFieldSetMapper" class="input.fieldsetmapper.HeaderFieldSetMapper"/>
<bean id="payloadFieldSetMapper" class="input.fieldsetmapper.PayloadFieldSetMapper"/>
<bean id="footerFieldSetMapper" class="input.fieldsetmapper.FooterFieldSetMapper"/>
```

here is what I get in the log during the bean instanciation

```
2020-04-21 10:22:32.491 DEBUG 6808 --- [           main] o.s.beans.TypeConverterDelegate          : Original ConversionService attempt failed - ignored since PropertyEditor based conversion eventually succeeded

org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [@org.springframework.lang.Nullable java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, java.lang.Class<java.beans.PropertyEditor>>] for value '{org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.Range[]=org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.RangeArrayPropertyEditor}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.lang.Nullable java.lang.Class<?>]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:129) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:604) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:219) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1748) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:171) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at Lanceur.main(Lanceur.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.lang.Nullable java.lang.Class<?>]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.MapToMapConverter.convertKey(MapToMapConverter.java:122) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.MapToMapConverter.convert(MapToMapConverter.java:84) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

And here is where the process is hanging indefinitely :

```
2020-04-21 10:22:36.261 DEBUG 6808 --- [cTaskExecutor-4] o.s.batch.core.scope.StepScope           : Creating object in scope=step, name=scopedTarget.itemReader
```

For your information, if I use another LineMapper, I don't run into this problem.

Another information, since I'm using Spring Boot, I had to override the StepScope definition to use the `scope="step"` property

```
<bean id="stepScope" class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope">
    <property name="autoProxy" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

**EDIT**
Here is an example of a line I have to map, its associated POJO and the interface it implements:

```
001234577589NNNNNN                   FFF                        M
```

```
@Data
public class Payload implements Element {

    private String debLine;

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String firstName;

    private String gender;

    private int numLine;
}
```

```
public interface Element {

    String getDebLine();

    int getNumLine();

    void setNumLine(int numLine);

}
```

Comment: `if I use another LineMapper, I don't run into this problem`: so it seems that the issue is with your current mapper. Looking at the error, you have a type conversion problem. Can you share an example of an input line and the target POJO you are trying to map it to? You need to find which type converter is missing.

Comment: Sloppy/paste error... You are passing the tokennizer to the fieldsetmappers.

Comment: @M.Deinum indeed, I fixed it

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I added the line and its POJO

Comment: @L.Malegue `indeed, I fixed it`. Did this fixed your issue or do you mean you fixed the typo in the description of your question but you still have the issue?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Sorry about that, I fixed the typo in the description.

Comment: I see no custom types in your POJO, so I don't see why this his happening. Please share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue and I will try to help.